# Google Apps Script JDBC connection problem

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script

I have problem to connect to any mysql database using jdbc connector in google apps scripts, I'm using tutorial code:

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://host(or ip):3306/database", "username", "password");
```

But in each case ( I've tested 4 different databases on 4 different host names) i get the same error:

> Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password. (line 2)

I'm looking for some help, I have no idea what could be the problem ;-(

ps. usernames/passwords are ok.
pps. In each database remote access is working ( I've tested by using telnet).

Comment: Ok, i found the solution, enabled mysql remote access is the key to the success :-)

Comment: Would you please tell me how you fix this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, It was almost 3 years ago, I don't remember all details, but I think, my previous comment is the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Since your issue was Remote access to a MySQL Database I will post some related documentation so that future viewers like TonyMiao will have a avenue to fix their own related issues.

### Step # 1: Login Using SSH (if server is outside your data center)

First, login over ssh to remote MySQL database server. You may need to login to your MySQL server as the root user:

```
ssh user@server1.cyberciti.biz
```

#### login as the root using su or sudo

```
su
```

#### or use sudo

```
sudo -i
```

OR directly login as root user if allowed:

```
ssh root@server1.cyberciti.biz
```

## Step # 2: Edit the my.cnf file

Once connected you need to edit the MySQL server configuration file my.cnf using a text editor such as vi:

If you are using Debian/Ubuntu Linux file is located at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` location.

If you are using Red Hat Linux/Fedora/Centos Linux file is located at `/etc/my.cnf` location.

If you are using FreeBSD you need to create a file `/var/db/mysql/my.cnf` location.

Edit the `/etc/my.cnf`, run:

```
# vi /etc/my.cnf
```

### Step # 3: Once file opened, locate line that read as follows

```
[mysqld] 
Make sure line skip-networking is commented (or remove line) and add following line

bind-address=YOUR-SERVER-IP
For example, if your MySQL server IP is 65.55.55.2 then entire block should be look like as follows:

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
language        = /usr/share/mysql/English
bind-address    = 65.55.55.2

# skip-networking
....
..
....
```

Where,

- bind-address: IP address to bind to.
- skip-networking : Donâ€™t listen for TCP/IP connections at all. All
  interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets. This option is
  highly recommended for systems where only local requests are allowed.
  Since you need to allow remote connection this line should be removed
  from my.cnf or put it in comment state.

### Step# 4 Save and Close the file

If you are using Debian / Ubuntu Linux, type the following command to restart the mysql server:

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

OR

```
# systemctl restart mysql
```

If you are using RHEL / CentOS / Fedora / Scientific Linux, type the following command to restart the mysql server:

```
# /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

OR

```
# systemctl restart mysqld
```

If you are using FreeBSD, type the following command to restart the mysql server:

```
# /usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server restart
```

OR

```
# service mysql-server restart
```

### Step # 5 Grant access to remote IP address

Connect to mysql server:

```
$ mysql -u root -p mysql
```

### GRANT ACCESS TO A NEW DATABASE

If you want to add a new database called foo for user bar and remote IP 202.54.10.20 then you need to type the following commands at mysql> prompt:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE foo;
mysql> GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO bar@'202.54.10.20' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

HOW DO I GRANT ACCESS TO AN EXISTING DATABASE?

Let us assume that you are always making connection from remote IP called 202.54.10.20 for database called webdb for user webadmin, To grant access to this IP address type the following command At mysql> prompt for existing database, enter:

```
mysql> update db set Host='202.54.10.20' where Db='webdb';
mysql> update user set Host='202.54.10.20' where user='webadmin';
```

### Step # 6: Logout of MySQL

Type exit command to logout mysql:

```
mysql> exit
```

### Step # 7: Open port 3306

You need to open TCP port 3306 using iptables or BSD pf firewall.

## A SAMPLE IPTABLES RULE TO OPEN LINUX IPTABLES FIREWALL

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

OR only allow remote connection from your web server located at 10.5.1.3:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 10.5.1.3 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

OR only allow remote connection from your lan subnet 192.168.1.0/24:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Finally save all rules (RHEL / CentOS specific command):

```
# service iptables save
```

## A SAMPLE FREEBSD / OPENBSD / NETBSD PF FIREWALL RULE ( /ETC/PF.CONF)

Use the following to open port # 3306 on a BSD based systems:

```
pass in on $ext_if proto tcp from any to any port 3306
```

OR allow only access from your web server located at 10.5.1.3:

```
pass in on $ext_if proto tcp from 10.5.1.3 to any port 3306  flags S/SA synproxy state
```

### Step # 8: Test it

From your remote system or your desktop type the following command:

```
$ mysql -u webadmin -h 65.55.55.2 -p
```

Where,

-u webadmin: webadmin is MySQL username
-h IP or hostname: 65.55.55.2 is MySQL server IP address or hostname (FQDN)
-p : Prompt for password
You can also use the telnet or nc command to connect to port 3306 for testing purpose:

```
$ echo X | telnet -e X 65.55.55.2 3306
```

OR

```
$ nc -z -w1 65.55.55.2 3306
```

Sample outputs:

```
Connection to 65.55.55.2 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!
```

Resource information: [Click Here!](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)