# JDBC/mysql Connection string issues from Google App Script

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script

I have the following code used to connect to a mySQL server from a Google App Script.  It was working prior to moving the server.  Now, even though I have entered the new information(address, names, pasword), it no longer works.  The error I am getting it "failed to establish a database connection.  Check connection string, username and password."  I am not familiar with servers and need to figure out how to fix this. I have Putty, but am unfamiliar with it - I tried, but it still would not connect. I have included my sanitized connection code below.

```
var address = //'address:port';
var user = //'username';
var userPwd = //'password';
var db = //'databasename';
var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db;

function testsql() { 
  var conn=Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl,user,userPwd);

  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("show databases"); 
  var dbList = stmt.executeQuery(); 
  dbList.next(); var row = 0; 
  Logger.log("Start of Log:"); 
  while(dbList.next()){ 
    Logger.log(dbList.getString(1)); row++; 
  } 
}
```

If the code is formatted correctly, is there another way to test the connection string?

I did find this question, but I am not 100% that is the problem.  [Google Apps Script JDBC connection problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536670/google-apps-script-jdbc-connection-problem)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

## Another Possibility

Your code looks okay to me.  But if you want to try something different, this one also creates a dialog to display all of the data.  You welcome to it.  I can tell you that I have a database on my website that I never could access but I moved over to a friends site and went right in.  I think the first site was probably blocking ip addresses from google to keep all of the web scrapers out.

```
function returnAQuery(q)
{
  var s = '';
  var address = //'address:port';
  var user = //'username';
  var userPwd = //'password';
  var db = //'databasename';
  var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db;
  s += dbUrl + ', ' + user + ', ' + userPwd + '<br />';
  s += q + '<br />';
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var results = stmt.executeQuery(q);
  if(results)
  {
    var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    for(var col = 0;col < numCols;col++)
    {
      if(col>0)s+=' , ';
      s += results.getMetaData().getColumnName(col + 1);
    }
    s += '<br />';
    while (results.next()) 
    {
      var rowString = '';
      for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) 
      {
        if(col>0)s+= ' , ';
        s += results.getString(col + 1);
      }
      s += '<br />';
    }
   var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(1200).setHeight(450);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'JDBC');
  }
  else
  {
    s += 'No results returned from query';
  }
}
```